# remote window utility viewer for internal networks

Tags: windows, remote, desktop, share

Screensharing applications I am very well familiar with.

However they are all a bit too heavy weight for what we are looking for.   Want to be able to quickly share a window/application and have that broadcast over the network to a remote viewer.  Very much how you would do a quick screengrab and email that to someone, but instead a live session.

This is very handy for development teams that sit in the same room where you can have someone say "hey look at this" where they can share a given portion of their desktop and quickly have someone remotely view that.

Has to work internally without relying on going out to a public internet server.

What solutions are available?

Comment: "Shopping questions," which this is, are off topic on the Stack Exchange network.  See:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: I do not at all understand the difference between what you want, and a typical screensharing application like VNC.

Comment: [Comparison of remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software)

Comment: This is not a "shopping question" by any stretch.

Comment: @mfinni the difference is simplicity.  Think of current screen grab utilities for sending a JPG of an area of your desktop.  Now think of that, as a quick view/window/portal for a colleague sitting across the room so they can quickly see an area of your screen shared.  Not unlike the utility that comes with Windows for magnifying areas of your desktop, but remote.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The difference is, sending a screenshot is *sending a file*. Sending a live-stream of another machine's screen *is* what remote framebuffers like VNC *do.* You can't send that *as a file*. That's why it's *not as simple.*

Answer (score 2):

*"hey look at this"* including screen / application view sharing is typically what [conferencing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_conferencing_software) is doing.

Comment: Conferencing software is too heavy weight, they come with way more than is required.  Basically looking for a remote-view utility.  There was one, but they stopped support for it when Windows Vista came along.

Comment: @AlanWilliamson You don't mean *NetMeeting* and its sucessors *Meeting Space* and [*SharedView*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharedView), which all are conferencing apps, do you?